# Can I join both static and dynamic widgets on flutter column/row/stack?

Tags: flutter

Lets say I have this:

```
child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text("This is my title"),),
]
```

is there a way for me to add List to this column after the static centered text? Or I must add use this method:

```
List<Widget> widgets();
widgets.add(Center(child: Text("This is my title"),));
for (var a=0;a<5;a++) {
widgets.add(Text("$a"));
}
```

and then add all list like this :

```
child: new Column(
              children: widgets
```

Comment: every widget is "dynamic" - there is no such concept like "static widget"

Comment: It's semantics. Not dynamic, hardcoded

Comment: so what do you want to achieve? in the below comment you say something about `setState` method, what is your goal actually?

Comment: To create a list which I can add items to on button click but I want the title to be hard coded

Comment: `makeColumn(data) {
  return Column(
    children: [Text('header, first form'), ...data.map((i) => Text('item #$i'))],
    //children: [Text('header, second form')] + data.map((i) => Text('item #$i')).toList(),
  );
}` - you can use it like `makeColumn([1,2,3])` for example

Comment: and how would i add/remove items to this list later? you suggest i'll assign the result of makeColumn to variable and use this variable as childrens ?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean: if you want to add use `add()` method, if you want to remove use one of `remove*()` methods, for example:  `var cnt = 33;
  var data = [];
  makeColumn() {
    return Column(
  children: [
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              data.add(cnt++);
              print(data);
            });
        },
          child: Text('add'),
        ),
        Text('header, first form'),
        ...data.map((i) => Text('item #$i'))
    ],
);
  }` - here: `data.add(cnt++);` is used to add new item to `data` array

Answer (score -3, accepted):

this is what i was looking for:

```
child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    Center(child: Text("This is my title"),),
    widgets()
]

...
...

Widget widgets() {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    for (var a=0;a<5;a++) {
        list.add(Text("$a"));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You are returning a List<Widget> but the return type is Widget, even if you change the return type you can't put a list of widgets like that inside the column. Also, if you want to modify the list from somewhere you don't have a reference of the list. I edited my answer with a similar approach to achieve something similar without these issues

Answer (score 7):

Here is a little example where you can have a centered title and a list of numbers. You can modify the list on tapping on a button:

```
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3];
```

If you want the title to scroll along with the list:

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Add number"),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          numbers.add(numbers.length + 1);
        });
      },
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text("This is my title"),
    ),
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: numbers.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, count) {
        return Text('Number: ${numbers[count]}');
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```

If you want the title to be fixed and scroll only the list:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Add number"),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          numbers.add(numbers.length + 1);
        });
      },
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text("This is my title"),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: numbers.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, count) {
          return Text('Number: ${numbers[count]}');
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Here is another simple alternative without using ListView.builder:

```
ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Add number"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            numbers.add(numbers.length + 1);
          });
        },
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text("This is my title"),
      ),
      Column(
        children: getWidgets(),
      ),
    ],
  )

List<Widget> getWidgets() {
  return numbers.map((number) => Text('Number: $number')).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand what you want i think this will help you

```
child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text("This is my title"),),

new Column(
children: ListMyWidgets(),
),
    ]
        ));
```

and then add new function returning dynamic content

```
List<Widget> ListMyWidgets() {
 List<Widget> list = new List();
list.add(Text("text1"))
list.add(Text("text2"))
list.add(Text("text..."))
 return list;
}
```

add `setState` after pressing button to see the effect

```
setState(() {  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> data = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

**You can use Spread operator (...) to combine**

```
Column(
    children: [
       Text("Hello This is title"),
       ...data.map((data) => Text(data))
     ],
),
```